# Silverlight horizontal carousel for thumbnails?

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml

UPDATE:

I have found this solution... modified it, but am struggling to get it to do a continuous cycle (1st item pops to last in list/array)

Any help is much appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Browser;

/*
*   A Image Carousel Demonstratoin in C#
*   from shinedraw.com
*/

namespace ImageCarousel
{
public partial class ImageCarousel : UserControl
{

    private String[] IMAGES = { "images/image1.png", "images/image2.png", "images/image3.png", "images/image4.png", "images/image5.png", "images/image6.png", "images/image7.png", "images/image8.png", "images/image9.png"};    // images
    private static double IMAGE_WIDTH = 128;        // Image Width
    private static double IMAGE_HEIGHT = 128;       // Image Height        
    private static double SPRINESS = 0.4;           // Control the Spring Speed
    private static double DECAY = 0.5;              // Control the bounce Speed
    private static double SCALE_DOWN_FACTOR = 0.05;  // Scale between images
    private static double OFFSET_FACTOR = 50;      // Distance between images
    private static double OPACITY_DOWN_FACTOR = 0.1;    // Alpha between images
    private static double MAX_SCALE = 1;            // Maximum Scale


    private double _xCenter;
    private double _yCenter;

    private double _target = 0;     // Target moving position
    private double _current  = 0;   // Current position
    private double _spring = 0;     // Temp used to store last moving 
    private List<Image> _images  = new List<Image>();   // Store the added images

    private static int FPS = 24;                // fps of the on enter frame event
    private DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer(); // on enter frame simulator

    public ImageCarousel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Save the center position
        //_xCenter = Width / 2;
        //_yCenter = Height / 2;
        _xCenter = 0;
        _yCenter = Height / 2;

        addImages();

        // add the click handler
        this.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ImageNaigation_MouseLeftButtonDown);

        // add the scroll handler
        HtmlPage.Window.AttachEvent("DOMMouseScroll", OnMouseWheel);
        HtmlPage.Window.AttachEvent("onmousewheel", OnMouseWheel);
        HtmlPage.Document.AttachEvent("onmousewheel", OnMouseWheel);
    }



    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
    // Handlers 
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

    // reposition the images
    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < _images.Count; i++){
            Image image = _images[i];
            posImage(image, i);
        }


        // compute the current position
        // added spring effect
        _spring = (_target - _current) * SPRINESS + _spring * DECAY;
        _current += _spring;
    }

    // define the new target by mouse wheel
    private void OnMouseWheel(object sender, HtmlEventArgs args)
    {

        double mouseDelta = 0;
        ScriptObject e = args.EventObject;
        // Mozilla and Safari    
        if (e.GetProperty("detail") != null)
        {
            mouseDelta = ((double)e.GetProperty("detail"));
        }

        // IE and Opera   
        else if (e.GetProperty("wheelDelta") != null)
            mouseDelta = ((double)e.GetProperty("wheelDelta"));

        mouseDelta = Math.Sign(mouseDelta);

        moveIndex((mouseDelta > 0) ? 1 : -1);
    }


    // define the new target by mouse click (Forward position only)
    void  ImageNaigation_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        moveIndex(1);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
    // Private Methods 
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////   


    // add images to the stage
    private void addImages(){
        for(int i = 0; i < IMAGES.Length; i++){
            // get the image resources from the xap
            string url = IMAGES[i];
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));

            // add and reposition the image
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(image);
            posImage(image, i);
            _images.Add(image);
        }
    }



    // move the index
    private void moveIndex(int value)
    {
        _target += value;
        _target = Math.Max(0, _target);
        _target = Math.Min(_images.Count - 1, _target);
    }

    // reposition the image
    private void posImage(Image image , int index){
        double diffFactor = index - _current;


        double left = _xCenter + ((IMAGE_WIDTH + OFFSET_FACTOR) * diffFactor);
        double top = _yCenter;


        image.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, left);
        image.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, top);

    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
    // Public Methods
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

    // start the timer
    public void Start()
    {
        // start the enter frame event
        _timer = new DispatcherTime`enter code here`r();
        _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000 / FPS);
        _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
        _timer.Start();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: download the Microsoft Surface SDK, it has a fantastic sample project that has a carousel, it works very smoothly and does not 100% depend on the Surface SDK, so you could retrofit it for your own silverlight purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how many items do you have in your list?

One very simple approach is to have a list box on your page, say with a width of 600px. Then wrap that in a canvas that has its clipToBounds property set to true, and have its width set to less than the list box, say 300px.

Then add buttons to the left and right of the canvas, and when you click them, you can set the RenderTransform of the list box to be a TranslateTransform, and shift it left X pixels (actually, animating this would be best, giving a smoother glide across) left or right (with some obvious bounds checkuing).

HTH

P.S. the reason I asked how many items, is because if you have hundreds of items, you may need to look into dynamically loading your items, or virtualising your list, which would change things a bit.

Comment: Is there a (2D) carousel plugin that I can use straight off instead of doing this from scratch?

Comment: not that I know of, but this wouldnt really be that difficult to implement